# How to group_by in mongoDb with the output results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Below is my code..

```
 group = {
    $group: { 
        "_id": {
            "user_email": "$user_email",
            "sender_email": "$sender_email"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }

    }
};  


Schema.aggregate(([group]),function(errors,results){

                  console.log(results);             
                  });
```

my output value is:

```
[ { _id: 
     { user_email: '123@gmail.com',
       sender_email: '235@gmail.com' },
    count: 5 },
  { _id: 
     { user_email: '123m@gmail.com',
       sender_email: '235@gmail.com' },
    count: 16 },
  { _id: 
     { user_email: '455@gmail.com',
       sender_email: '785@gmail.com' },
    count: 8 },
  { _id: 
     { user_email: '123@gmail.com',
       sender_email: '235@gmail.com' },
    count: 4 } ]
```

The above record shows the individual poke count.. i need to know that how many user_email has poked sender_email.(an user_email can poke a sender_email for many times but if the sender_email is poked for many times by a user_email i need not want the count as 'many' but i need the count as 1,in the same way if the various users have poked the sender_email i do not want the count of how many times each user has poked sender_email but how many user_email has poked sender_email). I need a mongoDb query for it?

```
{ user_email: '123@gmail.com',
       sender_email: '235@gmail.com' },
    count: 5 }
```

123@gmail.com poked 235@gmail.com for 5 times but i need to know the count of how many individual sender_email has been poked by various user_email without passing any parameter?

Below is my collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590182b3168e590182b315b2"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-04-27T12:37:03.385Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-04-27T05:33:39.563Z"),
    "user_email" : "123@gmail.com",
    "sender_email" : "235@gmail.com",
    "status" : 1,
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590182c4a182c4aaa2d21"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-04-27T12:37:03.385Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-04-27T05:33:56.122Z"),
    "user_email" : "123@gmail.com",
    "sender_email" : "235@gmail.com",
    "status" : 1,
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590184182c4a1821d98a028"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-04-27T12:37:03.385Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-04-27T05:39:40.425Z"),
    "user_email" : "561@gmail.com",
    "sender_email" : "235@gmail.com",
    "status" : 1,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: post your collection as well

Comment: ya i have updated my collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
group = {
    $group: { 
        "_id": {
            "user_email": "$user_email",
            "sender_email": "$sender_email"
        },
        "_id": {

            "sender_email": "$sender_email"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }

    }
};
```

My output:

```
[ { _id: { sender_email: '123@gmail.com' },
    count: 1 },
  { _id: { sender_email: '345@gmail.com' },
    count: 4 } ]
```

I have changed my query with that i have got the required output.